# Overlapping two line problem

Tags: leaflet, javascript, intersection, overlapping-features, turf

I want to check if 2 linestrings intersects (or overlaps) or no.

I use turf.js overlap.

Here are the results I want to get:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/volkancode/pen/oNNWjpX)

1- If only first or last points of line 1 intersects with first or last points of line 2, intersection test should return false.

2- If a part of line 1 overlaps with a part of line 2, intersection test should return true

Problem is here:

```
// button click event
button.addEventListener('click',function(){

  // line-A end point coord and line-B start point coord equal
  // result must be true
  var overlapping = turf.lineOverlap(long, short);
  L.geoJSON(overlapping, {color: 'white',opacity:0.6,lineCap:'butt'}).addTo(map);

  // Part of line-C overlaps line-D 
  // result must be false
  var overlapping = turf.lineOverlap(long1, short1);
  L.geoJSON(overlapping, {color: 'white',opacity:0.6,lineCap:'butt'}).addTo(map);

})
```

Comment: Please include your code (JS part) in the body of the question.

Comment: Added js part include my question

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the description (and example) of `turf.lineOverlap` function (see http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineOverlap), you will see that it returns overlaping line only if any whole line in first geometry overlaps with any whole line in the second geomtry. Partial overlap does not count.

If you want just to check if there is overlap between two lines that results in line, you can use `turf.booleanOverlap` function (see http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanOverlap). It return `true` if there is overlap.